# having data entry error in SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have been trying to get this database up and running for 4 days with the same error. I have exhausted all resources. anybody know what is happening here? This code is on my Main Activity.

```
public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, image BLOG)");

    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY
            );
        }
    });

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                        imageViewToByte(imageView)

                );
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entry Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edtName.setText("");
                edtPrice.setText("");
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FoodList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY) {
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void init() {
     edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
     edtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
     btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
     btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
     btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

}
```

}

Here is my SQLite Helper.Im very new to SQLite so I apologize for the ignorance.

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);


}
public void queryData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL(sql);
}

public void insertData(String name, String price, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO FOOD VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, name);
    statement.bindString(2, price);
    statement.bindBlob(3, image);

    statement.executeInsert();
}
public Cursor getData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

And this is my logcat readout.

```
12-18 17:17:12.468 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err: 

#################################################################
12-18 17:17:12.468 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err: Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
12-18 17:17:12.468 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err: Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
12-18 17:17:12.468 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:    (table FOOD has 3 columns but 4 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO FOOD VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?))
12-18 17:17:12.468 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err: #################################################################
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1008)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:573)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1306)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite.SQLiteHelper.insertData(SQLiteHelper.java:29)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
12-18 17:17:12.469 3678-3678/stash.media.devsolutionsbeyond.sqlite I/Choreographer: Skipped 513 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: You don't need to insert an ID column, if that's what you tried to do, but your question is missing the `SQLiteHelper` class

Comment: In any case, Android docs recommend not using raw SQL anymore. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: as error is stating, your FOOD table contains 3 columns but you provided null plus three placeholders as inserted values in your insert statement, why you supplied this null? does you table contains really three columns only? post the DB helper so that someone here can help you.

Comment: yes only need three columns. sorry just new at this. was following someone elses example but trying to change all the code to fit my app.

Comment: cricket_007 how can I safely remove ID Column

Comment: image BLOG? What is BLOG data type, its BLOB right?

Comment: two of your issues that need revising are : you have columns id (autonumber PK), name, and image but you read name, price and image, this is first issue. also your insert statement must match your number of columns which in total two unless you will add a price columnas id is autonumber.

Comment: damn my fat fingers lol fixed BLOB but still same error

Comment: will try to apply that shortly ams73 thank you

Comment: not only insert must match number of columns, also order of columns in base table as long as column names are not provided in the insert statement but only values.  so don't put price if you add it at last column in table, and provide its value as second parameter in the insert statement.

Comment: trying to follow...just cant seem to get it to work. I must not be doing something right

Answer (score 0):

Before running the App either add price column or change `insertData` method to :-

```
public void insertData(String name, String price, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO FOOD VALUES (null, ?, ?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, name);
    //statement.bindString(2, price); //<<<< needs price column
    statement.bindBlob(2, image);

    statement.executeInsert();
}
```

The above code works for me, at least when adding an entry (although I did use the following to avoid Null Pointer Exception and also to avoid getting an image) :-

```
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                        new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
                        //imageViewToByte(imageView)

                );
```

Instead of having an image. Perhaps use this at first as ass it stands the image to add can be null (i.e. you should validate input before inserting.)

### Adding the price column

If you go the add the price column route then Delete the App's data or ununstall the app and then change :-

`sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, image BLOG)");` to

`sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price TEXT image BLOG)");`

Notes!

- You very likely don't need **`AUTOINCREMENT`** and very likely don't want the drawbacks of using [**AUTOINCREMENT**](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).
- VARCHAR, VERYSTUPIDCHARFIELDTYPE etc is converted to column type TEXT, so TEXT has been used [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: tried this too. thank you though. problem now is when i hit btnList to show next activity it gives me error.

Comment: Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                                                     Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string

Comment: I commented out starting FoodList. You should ask a new question in that regard providing code for the `FoodList` class, as that would be where that issue is. But basically you have to use `getBlob()` rather than `getString()`.